# NsMutableArray object value only same value

Tags: iphone, ios5

I want to make `NSMutableArray` to store the touch time gap, but came across a problem:
The `NSMutableArray`'s count is only `1`.
What can I do?

```
NSInteger count = 0;
float firstTempTime = 0;
float nTempTime = 0;
float nTouchTimegap = 0;

#pragma mark –
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
messageLabel.text = @"Touches Began"; 
[self updateLabelsFromTouches:touches];  
NSArray *array = [touches allObjects];   
for (UITouch *touch in array){
    count = count +1;
    NSLog(@"began touch count: %d", count);

    nTempTime = [touch timestamp];
    NSLog(@"n TempTime stamp : %lf", nTempTime); 

    if (count == 1) {
        firstTempTime = [touch timestamp];
    }

    else {
        nTouchTimegap = nTempTime - firstTempTime;
        firstTempTime = nTempTime;
    }
    NSLog(@"nTouchTimegap : %lf", nTouchTimegap);

    nTouchTimegapArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
    [nTouchTimegapArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: nTouchTimegap]];


    for(id obj in nTouchTimegapArray){
        NSLog(@"nTouchTimegapArray : %i", [nTouchTimegapArray count]);
        NSLog(@"nTouchTimegapArray : %@", obj);
    }

}
```

Comment: And you could also create the array OUTSIDE of the loop, so you don't keep replacing the old one on each iteration.  (Hint: Objective-C is a *procedural* language.)

Answer (score 0):

`touchesBegan:` will be called once you touch the screen, if you touch the screen with a second finger it will be called again.

You should take a look at `touchesEnded:` and `touchesCancelled:`

Comment: NSMutableArray return only same object. Here are log.
2012-12-17 03:46:54.464 MTAS[13411:10703] nTouchTimegapArray : 1.3125
2012-12-17 03:46:54.464 MTAS[13411:10703] nTouchTimegapArray : 1.3125
2012-12-17 03:46:54.464 MTAS[13411:10703] nTouchTimegapArray : 1.3125
2012-12-17 03:46:54.464 MTAS[13411:10703] nTouchTimegapArray : 1.3125
2012-12-17 03:46:54.464 MTAS[13411:10703] -------------

Comment: I think there are problems
  
        for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {            
            [nTouchTimegapArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:nTouchTimegap]];
        }

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have to spell it out:

```
nTouchTimegapArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
[nTouchTimegapArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: nTouchTimegap]];
```

That sequence effectively erases the array on each iteration.  There's no possible way to ever have more than one entry in the array.

Move the first line out of the loop, and, if you want to accumulate touches from all invocations of the method, move it to the `init` routine or `viewDidLoad` or some such.

Comment: Absolutely correct, but I get the impression that the OP needs an example of the *correct* way of doing this, else he wouldn't be asking this question in the first place and/or your comment would have been enough. :)

Comment: the NSMutableArray's object log has only one value. I want to see All value(object) of NSMutableArray. T.T

Comment: @lnafziger -- I don't think he knows what he wants.